# Querying an Online XML document with Excel

Tags: xml, excel, vba

Querying from an excel document to update from a live XML data source (that I cannot edit or change in anyway).

The XML code from the web site

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<evec_api version="2.0" method="marketstat_xml">
  <marketstat><type id="24692">
      <buy><volume>58</volume><avg>187454397.24</avg><max>191102293.00</max><min>170620000.01</min><stddev>6655174.57</stddev><median>191000100.02</median><percentile>191102293.00</percentile></buy>
      <sell><volume>66</volume><avg>211618794.64</avg><max>266968892.26</max><min>202896968.00</min><stddev>11782399.14</stddev><median>206970995.32</median><percentile>202896977.39</percentile></sell>
      <all><volume>224</volume><avg>110889266.01</avg><max>266968892.26</max><min>0.99</min><stddev>30116759.19</stddev><median>186251523.01</median><percentile>0.99</percentile></all>
    </type></marketstat>
</evec_api>
```

My UDF excel module code

```
Function GetPrice(sItemID As String, sItem As String, Optional sURL = "", Optional sSystem = "") As Variant
Dim oHttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim xmlResp As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim result As Variant
On Error GoTo EH

If sURL = "" Then
    sURL = "http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid="
End If

If sSystem = "" Then
    sSystem = "&usesystem=30000142"
End If

'open the request and send it
oHttp.Open "GET", sURL & sItemID & sSystem, False
oHttp.Send

'get the response as xml
Set xmlResp = oHttp.responseXML
' get Item
GetPrice = xmlResp.getElementsByTagName(sItem).Item(0).Text

' Examine output of these in the Immediate window
Debug.Print sName
Debug.Print xmlResp.XML

CleanUp:
On Error Resume Next
Set xmlResp = Nothing
Set oHttp = Nothing
Exit Function
EH:
GetPrice = CVErr(xlErrValue)
GoTo CleanUp
End Function
```

When attempting to query for =GetPrice(24692, "//sell/min") excel returns #VALUE! error. When querying for =GetPrice(24692, "sell") will return 66211618794.64266968892.26202896968.0011782399.14206970995.32202896977.39
 which appears to be all the data from the sell line when I am looking to query for 202896968.00 with in the sell line data under the tag of min, and the max value within the buy tag to populate the Excel document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getElementsByTagName` method can only take a single tag name and not an XPath query. If you examine the `Text` property of a node which has child nodes (e.g. the "sell" node) then you get the text content of both the context node and of all of its child nodes.

Try using `selectNodes` instead and pass in an XPath query to your function, like this:

`GetPrice = xmlResp.selectNodes(sItem).Item(0).Text`

and use your original `=GetPrice(24692, "//sell/min")` formula

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  Use the DOMDocument method.  First, set a reference to Microsoft XML, V6.0.  Then the following code will retrieve the current value for the "Buy" "Max"

```
  Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
  xmlDoc.Load ("http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=24692&usesystem=30000142")

  buy_max = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("buy")(0).getElementsByTagName("max")(0).Text
```

You can expand, modify to retrieve whatever tags you need